# Save function inside macro for the function’s derivative

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, math-operators, function

My intent is to plot the first derivative of a function, following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/get-derivative-of-a-function) approach:

`f'(x) = (f(x + dx) - f(x))/dx`.

Mine is a bit of a long function, so I would like to know if it is possible to save it in a macro (or something similar) and then recall it later as

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{\A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(x))/(\b-\p)))}; 
produces the error 
*! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `x' (in '1* 0.7* ((exp(-0.7*(x))/(0.*
```

Minimal "working" example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0.7};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{0.4};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{1};
    %\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{\A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(x))/(\b-\p)))}; <-- failing attempt
    \begin{axis}[
    width=8cm, height=6cm,
    xmin=0.003, xmax=10,
    ymin=-0.2, ymax=0.8, 
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={at={(axis cs:10,0)},anchor=west},
    y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
    xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$r$},
    clip=false
    ]              
    \addplot [red, very thick, samples=100, smooth,domain=0.003:10]
        { \A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(x))/(\b-\p))) }; %
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I wish could calculate derivative as

```
(\A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(x+0.01))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(x+0.01))/(\b-\p))) - \f)/0.01
```

Or, were possible, with a simpler method

Comment: There is a way of fake the derivative https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193365/140722

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540650/plot-construction-for-a-velocity-vs-position-graph-interpolation-for-phase-diag

Answer (score 3):

First, a note on this:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0.7};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{0.4};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{1};
```

There should be no `;` here because these are not Ti*k*Z nor `pgfplots` statements like `\path`, `\draw`, `\addplot`, etc. These semicolons are the cause of the following error message (3 times) in the terminal output of TeX:

> Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!

Also, while using `\pgfmathsetmacro` is correct, it is heavy machinery for simple constants written directly in decimal form. I propose to use `\def` for these, which will be equivalent but faster.

(Beware of single-letter control sequences though... macros like `\c` or `\i` have a standard definition in LaTeX; in certain circumstances, you could experience problems when overridding them. That said, local def. + mostly-computation-code like here is probably “not too unsafe”.).

## pgfmath's `declare function` key

The tool you are looking for is `/pgf/declare function` (see *Customizing the Mathematical Engine* in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)).

Using this tool and a *dx* step of 0.1, your idea gives:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function = {
    f(\x) = \A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(\x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(\x))/(\b-\p)));},
  ]
  \def\b{0.7}
  \def\p{0.4}
  \def\A{1}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=8cm, height=6cm, ymin=-0.15, ymax=0.7,
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={at={(axis cs:10,0)}, anchor=west},
    y label style={at={(0,1)}, above},
    xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$r$},
    ]
    \addplot[red, very thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=0.003:10]
      { f(x) };
    \addplot[blue, very thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=0.003:10]
      { (f(x + 0.1) - f(x)) / 0.1 };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one uses the 0.01 step as in your question, the low accuracy of computations gives less pleasant results:

[image]

## Using `\fpeval` for better numerical accuracy

One can obtain good results with the 0.01 step using `\fpeval` (not from `pgfmath`, and in particular doesn't use the `fpu` library). This technique is slower and it is more cumbersome to give a usable expression of the “derivative” this way, but the result looks good:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}   % not needed if the LaTeX kernel is from 2022-06-01 or later
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{1}{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfmathfloattofixed{#1}%
  \let\x\pgfmathresult
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \fpeval{
      (\A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(\x + 0.01))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(\x + 0.01))/(\b-\p)))
      - (\A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(\x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(\x))/(\b-\p)))))
      / 0.01}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function = {
    f(\x) = \A * \b * ((exp(-\b*(\x))/(\p-\b)) + (exp(-\p*(\x))/(\b-\p)));},
  ]
  \def\b{0.7}
  \def\p{0.4}
  \def\A{1}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=8cm, height=6cm, ymin=-0.15, ymax=0.7,
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={at={(axis cs:10,0)}, anchor=west},
    y label style={at={(0,1)}, above},
    xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$r$},
    ]
    \addplot[red, very thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=0.003:10]
      { f(x) };
    \addplot[blue, very thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=0.003:10]
      { g(x) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! One last question: can I declare more than one function?

Comment: Yes, this is shown in the manual I pointed you to: you simply need to put a `;` at the end of each definition: for instance, `declare function = {f(\x) = ... ; g(\x) = ... ;}`. Unrelated: in my latest edit, I've added an accurate solution with step 0.01.